# Web UI for java code

Tags: java, html, user-interface, servlets, web-applications

Hi good people of Stackoverflow!

I'm currently in the process of redesigning a lot of testsoftware for testing DSL-linecards. The original software is build with C# and windows forms, and coupled closer than my asscheecks on a hot summerday. So it's no surprise they wanted something new and dynamic. But that they wanted it in Java was a surprise to me - I've never done java (C Power!), but hey - it's just a language.

Anyway, I'm almost finished with the data access- and businesslogic. Now the scary part begins. They want it runnning as a webapplication with a goodlooking, easy to use, design. I've done a couple of websites before in with ASP.NET, but never in the Java-domain.

**So my question is...**
what do you guys think I should use to develop the userinterface? I've made a small administrationprogram with JSP and Servlets on a Raspberry, but I don't want this as my only option. I'd really like to know what you guys think, your oppionions, pro's and cons.

So what do I need? I need to make a *good looking*, dynamic, multiuser, easy-maintainable and stable webapplication.

It's pretty simple. The user can choose an existing test and run it, or make a new test. It can run multiple tests on multiple cards, or schedule them.

My thoughts on the end design could be in the area of Nessus:
[image]
What would you do? Would you stick with JSP / Servlets, HTML5, CSS and JS? Do you have any recomendations for some frameworks? Anything would be helpful. If you haven't noticed, I've never really did webapplications before, other than personal or schoolprojects - so really, anything is useful :)

THANK YOU for your time, and have a great day :)

Comment: I've reseached further and found a buttload of frameworks - just scared me even more. One seems better than the other, and both looks complex as heck. My goal is to use my existing businesslogic code, which is build on solid principles (And actually SOLID - lol), and then just put a GUI on top. I really hope you guys can help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSF http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/javaserverfaces-139869.html.
 JSF is very productive and easy-maintainable.

Furthermore has a serie of frameworks to build the user interface, like [http://www.primefaces.org/](http://Primefaces)

Of course, you can customize your JSF app with css.

Comment: Hi Pedro.
Thanks for the answer! A quick google shows that theres a lot of sceptics against JSF, and pointing to using frameworks like Grails. What is your opinion on that?

Comment: Honestly I never used Grails professionally, but keep in mind that Grails was developed with Groovy (which is not exactly Java although belongs to the same platform).
The good side of Grails is not use xml files (like as Spring Framework uses), which makes programming easier. What I like of JSF is that I can programing like a desktop application (no need to explicitly set an ajax call for example, but just call the bean method). Furthermore I do not need to worry about html code.
Spring is another very good framework in which you will use JSP pages (more like HTML).

Comment: Everything will depend on your current and future needs. I recommend you this post that discusses the main Java web frameworks: [http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/the-curious-coders-java-web-frameworks-comparison-spring-mvc-grails-vaadin-gwt-wicket-play-struts-and-jsf/](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/the-curious-coders-java-web-frameworks-comparison-spring-mvc-grails-vaadin-gwt-wicket-play-struts-and-jsf/)
Make a good choice!